# Defining Array in RAML

Tags: api, mule, raml

I have a requirement where we have to define one of the headers as an array in RAML 1.0.
It works fine in anypoint API platform. But, I'm not able to supply input values to it.

Anyone have similar experience defining an array in raml 1.0 header?

```
#%RAML 1.0
baseUri: https://mocksvc.mulesoft.com/mocks/5b0f764c-844a-4a70-a188-d48a50bcc532
title: arraytest
version: v1
types:
  array1:
    type: object
    properties: 
      name:
        type: string
/arraycheck:
  get:
    headers: 
      x-arraynos:
        type: array
        items: array1
    responses: 
      200:
        body: 
          application/json:
            example: {"aa":"aa"}
```

Comment: Can you put an example of the RAML fragment you have defined for that header?

Comment: #%RAML 1.0
baseUri: https://mocksvc.mulesoft.com/mocks/5b0f764c-844a-4a70-a188-d48a50bcc532
title: arraytest
version: v1
types:
  array1:
    type: object
    properties: 
      name:
        type: string
/arraycheck:
  get:
    headers: 
      x-arraynos:
        type: array
        items: array1
    responses: 
      200:
        body: 
          application/json:
            example: {"aa":"aa"}

Answer (score 1):

You can try following code, which is optimised.

```
#%RAML 1.0
baseUri: https://mocksvc.mulesoft.com/mocks/5b0f764c-844a-4a70-a188-d48a50bcc532
title: arraytest
version: v1
types:
  array1:
    type: object
    properties:
      name:
        type: string[]
/arraycheck:
  get:
    headers:
      x-arraynos:
        type: array1
    responses:
      200:
        body:
          application/json:
            example: {"aa":"aa"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this example by the [RAML 1.0 spec](https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec/blob/master/versions/raml-10/raml-10.md#headers).

This ilustrate the problem that you are having:

```
#%RAML 1.0
title: Example with headers
traits:
  chargeable:
    headers:
      X-Dept:
        type: array
        description: |
          A department code to be charged.
          Multiple of such headers are allowed.
        items:
          pattern: ^\d+\-\w+$
          example: 230-OCTO
  traceable:
    headers:
      X-Tracker:
        description: A code to track API calls end to end
        pattern: ^\w{16}$
        example: abcdefghijklmnop
/users:
  get:
    is: [ chargeable, traceable ]
    description: |
      The HTTP interaction will look like

      GET /users HTTP/1.1
      X-Dept: 18-FINANCE
      X-Dept: 200-MISC
      X-Tracker: gfr456d03ygh38s2
    headers:
      X-Dept:
        example: [ 18-FINANCE, 200-MISC ]
      X-Tracker:
        example: gfr456d03ygh38s2
```

Comment: let me try this